# Run standalone web app in Google Chrome without borders or toolbars

Tags: google-chrome

I need to run a web-based app inside Chrome but it must appear as if the app is standalone. I dont want any tools or frames to be visible.

Yes I know I can press F11 but this isnt sufficient as I dont want the tools to appear when I move the mouse to the top of the screen.

Do I need to go to the extents of making a Chrome extension and utilizing a possible fullscreen feature?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Start Chrome with the `--kiosk` flag. Then, no borders etc. will be shown. Furthermore, pressing F11 will not exit this mode, so it's the most effective way of running a Kiosk-like app.

```
chromium --kiosk http://example.com/
```

Replace `chromium` with the path of your actual Chrome executable (e.g. `chrome.exe`).

In the new Chrome (v88) it might be required to add `--user-data-dir` parameter to remove the title bar, so the line would go like this:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\temp --kiosk http://google.com
```

If you open Chrome in app mode, like Trever suggests, then borders will still be visible.

Comment: Ah, neat +1. This isn't documented in my version of `google-chrome`, though I'm used to a lack of some features that come with Win/Mac versions. I run a [tiling window manager](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) - I don't have borders or title bars for any application on my system.

Comment: @TrevorSenior `man chromium` shows very little information at my side too. If you want up-to-date information, I suggest to take a look at the list of flags generated from the source code: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Cool this worked perfectly but I just realised I have to do this on iPad so I will have to check I can apply this solution there...

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Windows 7. But if I use -app=<url> it works (no borders)

Comment: This didn't work for me either on Linux Mint. I'll try with -app= instead

Comment: works for me with the latest verison of chrome on a windows 8.1 tablet

Comment: I've written an article about the subject. http://alinacierdem.com/index.php/software/25-standalone-javascript-application-with-chromium

Comment: Or after a bit of digging I just use "taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe".

Comment: tested today... use of --kiosk in a shortcut open a tab in google chrome Main windows browser....

Answer (score 49):

From the linux man page:

```
--app=URL
          Runs URL in "app mode": with no browser toolbars.
```

e.g. invoke it with `google-chrome --app=http://example.com`

Comment: Note: App mode still shows window borders. Kiosk mode is advised for the OP.

Comment: Although Rob is absolutely right, i just love this answer - fantastic way to make cloud 9 IDE run locally just like a "real" native app

Comment: this one works for me; I created a shortcut and used the chrome.exe --app=URL

Answer (score 7):

If you want a windowed app with no menus on mac, the steps have changed since @PaulR responded.

The new steps are as follows:

navigate to

```
chrome://flags
```

Enable the following two options:

1. "The new bookmark app system"
2. "Allow hosted apps to be opened in windows"

Restart Chrome to enable the options.
Then navigate to the page you want to turn into an "app".
In the tools menu (three dots) click More Tools > Add to Applications

Finally, navigate to

```
chrome://apps
```

and right click on the icon for the newly added Application. Enable the "Open as window" option.

Comment: This worked for me except the More Tools option was "Create Shortcut…" - This allowed me to drag the icon into my Dock and open standalone.

Comment: yeah, answer needs updating

Comment: Those flags seem to be gone now.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and create the shortcut, then open Chrome Apps `chrome://apps`. The shortcut icon should be in there. Right click on the app icon and check "Open as window." After that, the shortcut will open as a window.

Credit: [Janos_](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/YM7JYa8Dgts)

Answer (score 1):

You can create create shortcuts from Chrome itself....

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en-GB

^ this link no longer works.

The feature is called "Create application shortcuts". To enable it in newer versions of Chrome, go to:

```
chrome://flags/
```

... using the address bar. Then find "The new bookmark app system" and Disable it. Then click Relaunch Now at the bottom of the screen.

Now, in the "More tools" menu there will be the "Create application shortcuts" menu entry.

There may be another way to do this, but this is just clarifying the method that was supposed to be described in the link.

Comment: This doesn't seem to talk about create shortcuts any more that I can see? Either way link only answers are bad. You should put any relevant information from the link into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like many others have said, `--app=<url>` should do it for Chrome Version: `83.0.4103.61`. The `--kiosk` option opens a chrome tab, not a borderless "app" window. I'm on macOS Catalina and decided to `brew cast install chromium` and ran:

```sh
chromium --app=https://netflix.com
```

Unfortunately I [could not stream](https://itsfoss.com/watch-netflix-in-ubuntu-linux/#:~:text=You'll%20have%20to%20enable,to%20run%20Netflix%20on%20Chromium.) Netflix from Chromium..